# Generating images using MetaUML

Tags: diagram, uml

How do you generate images(*.svg, *.gif, *.png ...) with [MetaUML](http://metauml.sourceforge.net/old/index.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MetaUML is built on top of MetaPost, which is a tool used with LaTeX to typeset documents. So the output of the MetaUML is ment as graphics for LaTeX documents, which is a PostScript based vector graphics format similar to EPS. You can find more on the MetaPost wiki page.

However you can convert the resulting file, just google "metapost to svg" for example, first hit is this tutorial: http://www.tlhiv.org/MetaPost/tools/mptosvg/